# Separate text if capitalized in R

Tags: r, regex

I have this vector:

```
musicians <- c("AlanisMorisette","ACDC","PearlJam")
```

And I would like to separate the text based on the capital letter. But if there are two or more capital letters you can't separate them, so the result should be:

```
[1] "Alanis Morisette" "ACDC" "Pearl Jam"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your string has commas and parenthesis... why don't you use those to split up the string. Seems way easier than counting capital letters? What if you have "will.i.am" or some other artist that doesn't capitalize their name?

Comment: Hello @JeffC, perhaps I am wrong but `musicians` is a vector. How could I separate by commas? I'll edit my question to be clearer. In the case of will.i.am, it shouldn't be separated.

Comment: Sorry... I don't do R so when you said "I have this string...", I was taking you literally... that you had a string. I'm assuming it's something like an array, which would make sense given the syntax.

Comment: Don't worry @JeffC, your comment made me improve the question, and I tried with will.i.am. The answer below works fine even for the musician you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with capture groups by adding a space between lowercase and uppercase character. I changed the last value to `'PearlJamAnd'` to show that this works for more than 2 words.

```
musicians <- c("AlanisMorisette","ACDC","PearlJamAnd")
gsub('([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1 \\2', musicians, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Alanis Morisette" "ACDC"             "Pearl Jam And"
```

Comment: "Pearl Jam And"?

Comment: Hello @Ronak, what a great solution. I tried with this vector: `musicians <- c("AlanisMorisette","ACDC","MightyMightyBostons","will.i.am")` and returned the right answer: `[1] "Alanis Morisette"      "ACDC"                  "Mighty Mighty Bostons"
[4] "will.i.am"    `

Comment: Please, just let me ask a question: does it work like grouping? How is it working?

Comment: This looks for a lowercase letter (referred to as `\\1`) which is followed by uppercase letter (`\\2`) and adds a space between them (`\\1 \\ 2`)

Comment: That is new for me!, every day I learn something new. Thank you very much!